# How can I format a resource string?

Tags: javascript, jquery, string-formatting

I have this snippet so far:

```
    resetSettings: function (type, showConfirm, OnImageLoad) {
        if (showConfirm) {
            var msg = "";
            Localization.GetBrowserLocalResource("ConfirmMsg", function (key, value) {
                msg = value;
            });
```

But I want to format it with something like this, where I pass in the type to format the string:

```
Localization.stringFormat(getString(Localization.GetBrowserLocalResource("ConfirmMsg", type)));
```

But I need to format the string with the function(key,value) in that method. How do I do that?

EDIT:

Definition of GetBrowserLocalResource:

```
    var browserLocalResources = {};

    // callback =  callback(key,value)
    GetBrowserLocalResource: function (key, callback) {

        var val = "--no--resource";

        if (browserLocalResources != null) {

            if (browserLocalResources.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                val = browserLocalResources[key];
                callback(key, val);
            } else {
                Localization.GetResourceFromServer(key, callback);
            }

        } else {
            AjaxLog.WriteLog("error: GetBrowserLocalResource", "browserLocalResources == null");
        }

        return (val);
    },
```

How would I use my stringFormat?

stringFormat is:

```
stringFormat: function () {

            var s = arguments[0];
            for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length - 1; i++) {       
                var reg = new RegExp("\\{" + i + "\\}", "gm");             
                s = s.replace(reg, arguments[i + 1]);
            }

            return s;
        }
```

Something like this?:

```
if (showConfirm) {
                var msg = "";
                stringFormat(Localization.GetBrowserLocalResource("ConfirmMsg"), type, function (key, value) {
                    msg = value;
                });
```

Comment: Where is `Localization.GetBrowserLocalResource` defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to be able to call `Localization.GetBrowserLocalResource` with an optional second parameter. You'll have to modify that function. This should get you started on defining an optional parameter to a method:

```
// type is optional
// callback =  callback(key,value)
GetBrowserLocalResource: function (key, type, callback) {

    if (typeof callback === 'undefined' && typeof type === 'function') {
        callback = type;
        type = void 0;
    }

    // ...
},
```

(of course, if `type` isn't going to be optional, but will always be required, then just add the parameter and don't add the type checking)

Once you've made this change, then you can call the method like this:

```
resetSettings: function (type, showConfirm, OnImageLoad) {
    if (showConfirm) {
        var msg = "";
        Localization.GetBrowserLocalResource("ConfirmMsg", type, function (key, value) {
            msg = Localization.stringFormat(GlobalObjects.getString(value);
        });
```

Comment: Okay but how would I use stringFormat then? See edit.

Comment: type should be optional in my case. It's not showing the formated string... it still has the placeholder in the string ({0}) but I'll run the debugger.